# Was meint Ulrich Engel? (Frage zu Tempora)

Tags: tense

In "Deutsche Grammatik" (3. Auflage) geht Ulrich Engel ab Seite 494 (V 150) hart mit der üblichen Darstellung des deutschen Tempussystems ins Gericht. Er schreibt nun:

> Wer nämlich sagt
>   *Handwerker haben ihn getragen. Kein Geistlicher begleitete ihn.*
>   meint etwas grundsätzlich anderes, als wenn er sagen würde:
>   *Handwerker trugen ihn. Kein Geistlicher hat ihn begleitet.*

Ich interpretiere beide Sätze nur so, dass Handwerker jemanden tragen und kein Geistlicher dabei ist, und beides in der Vergangenheit liegt. Gemeint ist vermutlich ein unwürdiges Begräbnis. Oder kann jemand beide Sätze tatsächlich völlig anders interpretieren?

Mir ist klar, dass Perfekt und Präteritum eine unterschiedliche Bedeutung haben können, einen *deutlichen* Unterschied sehe ich hier jedoch nicht. Ein Beispiel für einen deutlichen Unterschied ist:

> Die Katze meines Nachbarn bekam (irgendwann) Junge.
>   Die Katze meines Nachbarn hat Junge bekommen (, sie tapsen durchs Haus).

Ersteres nimmt man, wenn das Ergebnis egal, letzteres, wenn das Ergebnis relevant ist. Mir ist jedoch schleierhaft, wie das auf das Beispiel von Engel anwendbar ist, zumal *deutlich*.

Comment: Meiner Ansicht nach nicht. Also, schon, aber nur wenn man wirklich ganz ganz dolle will. Und selbst wenn... das Wort "grundsätzlich" halte ich auf jeden Fall für übertriebenstens. Was schreibt der denn, was der Unterscheid sei. Ist.

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt einen grundsätzlichen Unterschied zwischen Perfekt und Imperfekt, auch wenn der in modernem Deutsch nicht mehr so wahrgenommen wird.

Als Schlussteil einer erzählenden Handlung mit abschließender Reflektion geht nur die zweite Version. Die erste wirkt (in diesem Kontext), auch wenn man nicht bewusst darüber nachdenkt, holprig und falsch.

Allerdings würde ich diesen Unterschied nicht durch "meint etwas grundsätzlich anderes" ausdrücken. Ein *Aspekt* der Handlung ist anders, aber nicht die grundlegende Bedeutung. Insofern kann man die Sätze also nicht "*völlig* anders" interpretieren.